# Html form submission: Can form data be submitted to more than one destination?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am creating a quiz application which contains two files:

**question.php** and **process.php**

In `question.php`, the user enters his answer in a textbox and clicks a submit button which, by means of a form, has the input he provides processed in a `process.php` file.
 After processing the input, the `process.php` file redirects the user to a new question.

Now the problem is that before redirecting the user to a new question I want the textbox to glow red if his answer is incorrect and green if correct. 
However this obviously needs to be done in the javascript code of the `question.php` file.

Since the user's input has been sent to the process.php file, I doubt that there is any way of referencing `$_POST['answer']` in my `question.php`'s javascript.

In question.php I have the form:

```
<form method="post" action="process.php">
```

In `question.php` I wish to alter the background color of the textbox according to the user's answer. This code is obviously wrong, but it should give you an idea of what I have in mind.

```
if(<?php echo $_POST['answer']; ?p> != correctAnswer)
document.getElementById('blankSpace').background-colour = red;
```

The only solution that I can think of is to have the form data submitted to both files. Is this possible?

Comment: I think you will need AJAX for your issue.

Comment: No. You submit the answers via AJAX to the process-file, and depending on what comes back, you process either "next question", glow green, glow red, put a laughing audio track on because the user is stupid, and so on and so forth..

Comment: You don't need to submit your data to more than one destination. Your question is a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). As others have commented, you may use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: A better solution - and considering @JordiNebot's comment - is to handle all the functionality within a single PHP file and avoid the problem you're trying to solve. With careful code structure (for example, separation of the UI and logic) you should be able to keep the code clean and readable.

Answer (score 0):

you will do an ajax call to process.php and based on what process.php returns you do the glow and do a

`window.location.assign('question.php')`

that should do the magic